# Is it possible to state strong normalization through set inclusion?

Tags: lambda-calculus, normal-forms, term-rewriting

In an abstract rewriting system $\langle A, \rightarrow\rangle$, confluence may be stated by using set inclusion. Namely, a rewriting system is confluent iff ${\leftarrow^*\rightarrow^*}\ {\subseteq}\ {\rightarrow^*\leftarrow^*}$ (or equivalenty as the Church-Rosser theorem, ${\leftrightarrow^*}\ {\subseteq}\ {\rightarrow^*\leftarrow^*}$). Factorization for essential and inessential steps (e.g., head and inner reduction in the $\lambda$-calculus) may be stated by set inclusion as well: ${\rightarrow^*}\ {\subseteq}\ {\rightarrow_e^*\rightarrow_i^*}$. Is there a way to state strong normalization for $\rightarrow$ through a set inclusion as well? Formally, are there sets (preferably binary relations) $X$ and $Y$ such that $X \subseteq Y$ if and only if $\rightarrow$ is strongly normalizing?